# Pushforward of a Markov kernel under a measurable mapping

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
- $\mathcal E_b:=\left\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\right\}$ be equipped with the supremum norm;
- $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$.
- $(\tilde E,\tilde{\mathcal E})$ be a measurable space;
- $\varphi:E\to\tilde E$ be $\left(\mathcal E,\tilde{\mathcal E}\right)$-measurable with $\varphi(E)=\tilde E$ and $$\kappa\left(\tilde f\circ\varphi\right)=\tilde g\circ\varphi\tag1$$ for all $\tilde f\in\tilde{\mathcal E}_b$.

Note that $\tilde g$ is uniquely determined and hence $$\tilde\kappa f:=\tilde g$$ is well-defined. Now, instead of  $(1)$, we could also consider the pushforward $$\hat\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;):=\varphi(\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;))$$ of $\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;)$ under $\varphi$ for $x\in E$.

The question is: Do $\hat\kappa$ and $\tilde\kappa$ coincide? I feel like that they should. At least the left-hand side of $(1)$ should be equal to $\hat\kappa\tilde f$. Now, doesn't the factorization lemma already imply the existence of $\tilde g$?

Additional question: Consider the particular case, $E=\mathbb R^d$ and $\tilde E=[0,1)^d$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$, both equipped with the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $$\iota:\mathbb R^d\to[0,1)^d\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor\tag2$$ and $\kappa$ is the normal distribution kernel with variance $\sigma^2I_d$ for some $\sigma>0$. Is in this scenario $(1)$ satisfied? This seems to be hard to verify ...